# Accent sensitive INSERTs

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have a MySQL table (collation: *utf8mb4_unicode_ci*) with the following fields:

> **sn** (PK, Int)
>
> **word** (Unique, Varchar, *utf8mb4_unicode_ci*)
>
> **meaning** (Text, *utf8mb4_unicode_ci*)

The **word** field can contain words with or without accent marks. Hence, *se* and *sé* may exist simultaneously as unique entries. Here's my query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `tbldictionary`(`word`, `mean`) VALUES ('sé','omething')
```

I ran this query when the table already has a field with *se* in the **word** column and it refused to enter *sé*. Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to without having to change the table's collation? I know I can use the **COLLATE** clause with **SELECT** queries but apparently that isn't available with **INSERT**.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without changing the collation of your table.